# UILabels not updating in custom prototype cell of UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Have tried several variations and watched different tutorials but cannot get my custom prototype cell to change from the defaulted text "label" in my tableviewcontroller. I have defined these labels as IBOutlets in the custom prototype file which is appropriately linked. I'm sure I missing something elementary here. Any thoughts?

```
import UIKit; import Parse

class UserRecordsTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

    // Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
    override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Configure the PFQueryTableView
        self.parseClassName = "Event"
        self.textKey = "category"
        self.textKey = "duration"
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = false
    }

    // Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "event")
        query.orderByAscending("category")
        return query
    }

    //override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject) -> PFTableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UserRecordsTableViewCell!

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UserRecordsTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }

        // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell    
        cell.durationEventLabel.text = object["duration"] as? String

        // Date for cell subtitle
        return cell
    }
}
```

Here is my cell:

```
import UIkit
class UserRecordsTableViewCell: PFTableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var dateEventLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var catEventLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var durationEventLabel: UILabel!

}
```

And under class in IB I have selected UserRecordsTableViewCell.

Comment: Did you change the class of your cell in IB to PFTableViewCell?

Comment: see additional edit to my question above, not sure that answers your question?

Comment: Yeah, that answers the question. I did mean UserRecordsTableViewCell, not PFTableViewCell. The only think I can think of to check is to do a println(cell) and println(object["duration"] )and see what they both give.

Comment: Little closer. Got catEventLabel updating, but durateEventLabel shows as blank. This one represents a Int in the DB. So maybe I'm not converting to string correctly, and the  line to show my date label                                                                              var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let dateForText = object["createdAt"] as NSDate 
        cell.dateEventLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateForText)  is giving unwrapping with unexpected nil error. Thanks in advance for any further insight.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that code. Are you sure that object["createdAt"] is returning an NSDate object?

Comment: Still struggling. I think I have isolated the issue to the required init section. I think that textKey can only be used once. Ive tried to create another class like textKey2 but thats not cutting it either.  I thrown in the towel on the concept of all three items being displayed and just shooting for catEventLabel and the date. But you were right, object["createdAt"] is not pulling from parse.  Any last thoughts on why that would not be working?

Comment: There's no way for me to know without seeing how you're putting the data into Parse in the first place. Have you looked at the Parse table (or whatever they call it) that you look at on their website to see what fields your object has, and whether there's data in them?

Comment: There is definitely a field createdAt in the DB that is showing date population. March 07, 2015, 04:56 is the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided the best approach to my desired look is to go with PFTableViewCell provided by parse framework and simply only show two items. Main category and date as subtitle. This is opposed to creating a custom cell which works well with text and image label but not well with two text keys. Followed this tutorial and was great:

https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-swift-parse-com-tutorial-set-up-xcode-project-part-2-of-3-31a17d1c6581